# Getting error on Downloading updates

Tags: 12.04, updates, update-manager, internet-connection

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main gnome-control-center-data all 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main gnome-settings-daemon amd64 3.4.1-0ubuntu1.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.188 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libgnome-control-center1 amd64 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main gnome-control-center amd64 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.22 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main mahjongg amd64 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.25 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main gnomine amd64 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.28 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main gnome-sudoku all 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main gnome-games-data all 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main gnome-orca all 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.155 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main grub-pc amd64 1.99-21ubuntu3.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.176 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main grub-pc-bin amd64 1.99-21ubuntu3.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.179 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main grub2-common amd64 1.99-21ubuntu3.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main grub-common amd64 1.99-21ubuntu3.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main gwibber amd64 3.4.1-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.188 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main gwibber-service all 3.4.1-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libgwibber2 amd64 3.4.1-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.22 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libgwibber-gtk2 amd64 3.4.1-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.25 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main gwibber-service-facebook all 3.4.1-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.28 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main gwibber-service-identica all 3.4.1-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main gwibber-service-twitter all 3.4.1-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libdevmapper-event1.02.1 amd64 2:1.02.48-4ubuntu7.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.155 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libedataserverui-3.0-1 amd64 3.2.3-0ubuntu7
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.176 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main liblvm2app2.2 amd64 2.02.66-4ubuntu7.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.179 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libnm-glib-vpn1 amd64 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libqtbamf1 amd64 0.2.4-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libreoffice-emailmerge all 1:3.5.3-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.188 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libreoffice-help-en-us all 1:3.5.3-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main unity-2d-shell amd64 5.12.0-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.22 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main unity-2d-panel amd64 5.12.0-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.25 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main unity-2d-spread amd64 5.12.0-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.28 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main unity-2d-common all 5.12.0-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libunity-2d-private0 amd64 5.12.0-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.2.0-24.39
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.155 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main policykit-1 amd64 0.104-1ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.176 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main python-gobject all 3.2.2-1~precise
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.179 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main python-software-properties all 0.82.7.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main python-zeitgeist all 0.9.0-1ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main remmina-plugin-vnc amd64 1.0.0-1ubuntu6
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.188 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main remmina-plugin-rdp amd64 1.0.0-1ubuntu6
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main remmina amd64 1.0.0-1ubuntu6
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.22 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main remmina-common all 1.0.0-1ubuntu6
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.25 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main smbclient amd64 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.28 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main samba-common all 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main samba-common-bin amd64 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main simple-scan amd64 3.4.1-0ubuntu1.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.155 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main software-center all 5.2.2.2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.176 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main software-properties-common all 0.82.7.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.179 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main software-properties-gtk all 0.82.7.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main ubuntuone-client-gnome amd64 3.0.1-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main unity-2d all 5.12.0-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.188 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main unity-greeter amd64 0.2.8-0ubuntu1.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main unity-lens-applications amd64 5.12.0-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.22 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main unity-lens-music amd64 5.12.0-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.25 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main unity-scope-musicstores amd64 5.12.0-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.28 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main vino amd64 3.4.2-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main xserver-xorg-input-synaptics amd64 1.6.0-0ubuntu1~precise1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main xserver-xorg-video-vmware amd64 1:12.0.1-1ubuntu1.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.155 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main xul-ext-ubufox all 2.0.3-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.176 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main zeitgeist-core amd64 0.9.0-1ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.179 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main zeitgeist all 0.9.0-1ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main zenity amd64 3.4.0-0ubuntu4
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main zenity-common all 3.4.0-0ubuntu4
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.188 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main indicator-sound amd64 0.8.5.0-0ubuntu2.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main shotwell amd64 0.12.3-0ubuntu0.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.22 80]
Fetched 58.6 MB in 38min 14s (25.6 kB/s)                                       
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-draw_3.5.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-gtk_3.5.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-gnome_3.5.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/python-uno_3.5.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-math_3.5.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-common_3.5.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-core_3.5.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/fonts-opensymbol_102.2+LibO3.5.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-style-human_3.5.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-style-tango_3.5.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/libwbclient0_3.6.3-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libxatracker1_8.0.2-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/libnm-util2_0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/libnm-glib4_0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/network-manager_0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-docs/ubuntu-docs_12.04.5_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libglu1-mesa_8.0.2-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/libsmbclient_3.6.3-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/utouch-geis/libutouch-geis1_2.2.9-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+3.0/gir1.2-gtk-3.0_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-sso-client/ubuntu-sso-client-gtk_3.0.0-0ubuntu2_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-sso-client/ubuntu-sso-client_3.0.0-0ubuntu2_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-sso-client/python-ubuntu-sso-client_3.0.0-0ubuntu2_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lvm2/libdevmapper1.02.1_1.02.48-4ubuntu7.1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lvm2/dmsetup_1.02.48-4ubuntu7.1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-tiny_7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-common_7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/hdparm/hdparm_9.37-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pygobject/python-gi-cairo_3.2.2-1~precise_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pygobject/python-gi_3.2.2-1~precise_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apport/python-problem-report_2.0.1-0ubuntu8_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apport/python-apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu8_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apport/apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu8_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apport/apport-gtk_2.0.1-0ubuntu8_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-core_2.4.2-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libu/libunity/libunity9_5.12.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nux/libnux-2.0-0_2.12.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nux/libnux-2.0-common_2.12.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/compiz-gnome_0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/compiz-plugins-default_0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/compiz-core_0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity/unity_5.12-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity/libunity-core-5.0-5_5.12-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity/unity-services_5.12-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity/unity-common_5.12-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nux/nux-tools_2.12.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.155 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/libdecoration0_0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.176 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/compiz_0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.179 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evolution-data-server/libedataserver-1.2-15_3.2.3-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evolution-data-server/libebackend-1.2-1_3.2.3-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evolution-data-server/libecal-1.2-10_3.2.3-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.188 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evolution-data-server/libedata-book-1.2-11_3.2.3-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evolution-data-server/libedata-cal-1.2-13_3.2.3-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.22 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evolution-data-server/evolution-data-server_3.2.3-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.25 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evolution-data-server/evolution-data-server-common_3.2.3-0ubuntu7_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.28 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evolution-data-server/libcamel-1.2-29_3.2.3-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evolution-data-server/libebook-1.2-12_3.2.3-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nautilus/libnautilus-extension1a_3.4.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.155 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libz/libzeitgeist/libzeitgeist-1.0-1_0.3.18-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.176 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nautilus/nautilus-data_3.4.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.179 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nautilus/nautilus_3.4.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/empathy/nautilus-sendto-empathy_3.4.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/empathy/empathy_3.4.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.188 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/empathy/empathy-common_3.4.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdb/gdb_7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.22 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/at-spi2-core/gir1.2-atspi-2.0_2.4.2-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.25 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtksourceview3/gir1.2-gtksource-3.0_3.4.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.28 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libu/libubuntuone/libubuntuoneui-3.0-1_3.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libu/libubuntuone/gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0_3.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libu/libunity/gir1.2-unity-5.0_5.12.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.155 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib-networking/glib-networking-services_2.32.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.176 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib-networking/glib-networking_2.32.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.179 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib-networking/glib-networking-common_2.32.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-control-center/gnome-control-center-data_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon_3.4.1-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.188 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-control-center/libgnome-control-center1_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-control-center/gnome-control-center_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.22 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-games/mahjongg_3.4.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.25 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-games/gnomine_3.4.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.28 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-games/gnome-sudoku_3.4.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-games/gnome-games-data_3.4.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-orca/gnome-orca_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.155 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/grub2/grub-pc_1.99-21ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.176 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/grub2/grub-pc-bin_1.99-21ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.179 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/grub2/grub2-common_1.99-21ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/grub2/grub-common_1.99-21ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gwibber/gwibber_3.4.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.188 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gwibber/gwibber-service_3.4.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gwibber/libgwibber2_3.4.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.22 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gwibber/libgwibber-gtk2_3.4.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.25 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gwibber/gwibber-service-facebook_3.4.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.28 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gwibber/gwibber-service-identica_3.4.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gwibber/gwibber-service-twitter_3.4.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lvm2/libdevmapper-event1.02.1_1.02.48-4ubuntu7.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.155 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evolution-data-server/libedataserverui-3.0-1_3.2.3-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.176 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lvm2/liblvm2app2.2_2.02.66-4ubuntu7.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.179 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/libnm-glib-vpn1_0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libq/libqtbamf/libqtbamf1_0.2.4-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-emailmerge_3.5.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.188 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-help-en-us_3.5.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity-2d/unity-2d-shell_5.12.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.22 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity-2d/unity-2d-panel_5.12.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.25 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity-2d/unity-2d-spread_5.12.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.28 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity-2d/unity-2d-common_5.12.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity-2d/libunity-2d-private0_5.12.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_3.2.0-24.39_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.155 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/policykit-1/policykit-1_0.104-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.176 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pygobject/python-gobject_3.2.2-1~precise_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.179 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/python-software-properties_0.82.7.1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zeitgeist/python-zeitgeist_0.9.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/remmina/remmina-plugin-vnc_1.0.0-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.188 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/remmina/remmina-plugin-rdp_1.0.0-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/remmina/remmina_1.0.0-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.22 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/remmina/remmina-common_1.0.0-1ubuntu6_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.25 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/smbclient_3.6.3-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.28 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/samba-common_3.6.3-2ubuntu2.2_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/samba-common-bin_3.6.3-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/simple-scan/simple-scan_3.4.1-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.155 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-center/software-center_5.2.2.2_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.176 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/software-properties-common_0.82.7.1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.179 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/software-properties-gtk_0.82.7.1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird_12.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird-gnome-support_12.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntuone-client-gnome/ubuntuone-client-gnome_3.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity-2d/unity-2d_5.12.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.188 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity-greeter/unity-greeter_0.2.8-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity-lens-applications/unity-lens-applications_5.12.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.22 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity-lens-music/unity-lens-music_5.12.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.25 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity-lens-music/unity-scope-musicstores_5.12.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.28 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/update-manager/update-manager_0.156.14.4_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/update-manager/update-manager-core_0.156.14.4_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vino/vino_3.4.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics_1.6.0-0ubuntu1~precise1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xserver-xorg-video-vmware/xserver-xorg-video-vmware_12.0.1-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  Connection fai
```

Comment: Try changing Download Server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. First confirm that you are able to browse other websites.
2. Then, Run this commands:

   `sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists{,bakjune4}`
    `sudo mv /var/cache/apt/archives/partial{,bakjune4}`
    `sudo apt-get update`
    `sudo apt-get upgrade`

3) If above commands run successfully fine you can remove the above bakjune4 directories safely.

Otherwise change the download server using update manager. Follow this:

Update-manager -> Settings -> Ubuntu Software (first tab) -> Change the server in Download from box.

Run check for updates and install updates if any.

**Note:**
In any case you can revert to your current situation by using following commands:

- `sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/`
- `sudo mv /var/lib/apt/list{bakjune4,}`
- `sudo mv /var/cache/apt/archives/partial{bakjune4,}`

Comment: Thanx a lot jrg. Now it working properly... :)

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, it'd be great if you accept the solution as the correct solution by clicking on the 'right' sign at the beginning of the solution which helped you. :)